# Using All CPU Cores With GNU Parallel

Tags: ubuntu

Is it possible to use all cpu cores in ubuntu server with gnu parallel for a program? I will use hashcat program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNU Parallel to use all CPU cores, but it is useless to do so if the goal is to run hashcat. hashcat will run on all cores automatically (so says [the first result I found on google](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-6653.html#:%7E:text=And%20yes%2C%20it%20will%20use%20all%20cores.)).

The main problem wwhen solving one problem with parallel resources is sharing out the problem space so that the different resources do not uselessly duplicate work by working on the same part of the problem. GNU Parallel is a general-purpose program for sharing load, and will leave    you quite a lot of work to do, while hashcat is designed for the task and will natively do the load sharing. It will also use a GPU if you have one, which is good if you actually want to brute-force a password.